# How would I ensure Vulkan environment variables are set

Tags: c++, cmake, glfw, vulkan

To preface this; I'm still fairly new to C++/CMake so apologies if the answer to this is glaringly obvious.

I've recently been playing around with Vulkan and GLFW (C++) and everything works as expected. I set the following environment variables within the CLion runtime configuration: VULKAN_SDK, DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, VK_LAYER_PATH and VK_ICD_FILENAMES which all ensure Vulkan can find what it expects.

But that got me thinking. If I were to ever create something that I'd like to release to end users, is there a way for me to automatically set these environment variables at runtime or through CMake? I can't imagine it being logical to expect end users of, say, a game to set environment variables prior to running the application.

Comment: Typically games ship with a small loader script that sets these variables and `exec` into the real game. Alternatively you can look at RPATH and friends.

Comment: Thanks for the info there. Could you elaborate a little with regards to RPATH and friends?

Comment: With RPATH you can make your binary look for libraries relative to its location (since you needed to set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH)